# Connect to a Local Oracle Database (LOCALHOST) from another System that is connected via lan

Tags: jdbc, network-programming

I need to connect to my local oracle database from another system, but I do not know what to give in the host name. I was previously giving localhost but that is not working as well as host name of the system is not working.

Can we connect to a local db from another system?

```
public static Connection local_loginConnection() {
    try{
        Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@10.152.96.208:1521:XE","root","root");
        return conn;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println(e);
        return null;
    }
}
```

Any pointers to resolve this issue?

Comment: Check the hostname of your system with the domain name and try replacing the IP, if that helps!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the IP-address of your host is reachable from the other host that is possible (you also have to configure your host to allow connections to the database (adjust firewall), and you have to make sure the db-server listens on the external interface too). Make sure to ensure proper authentication/access control, if you expose your server (anything actually) on any network other than a direct link like that.

Your address (10.x.x.x) suggests you are on a private network, so you won't be able to reach it from the outside (Internet), but only from another host within that network unless you have dnat or something similar in place at the network boundary.

If you want to use a DNS-name you will of course have to have a DNS-server map that name to your host's IP-address.

However it should also be possible to use the IP-address instead of the hostname. Of course you would have to adjust the IP-address every time it changes, but I assume yours is a pure test-setup so that may be acceptable.